# Restkit/CoreData - Updating an entity's attribute does not update UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, restkit

I have an entity `Country` that includes an attribute `downloaded` which has a default value of 0, and is NOT mapped by RestKit. I want to be able to group my tableView into sections based on this downloaded attribute. Everything works as expected, until I try to programmatically change the downloaded value myself. Code below:

Where I'm trying to set the value - my context is the `mainQueueManagedObjectContext` that has been passed to the controller through the AppDelegate.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    Country *country = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [FGDataCalls downloadFieldGuide:country.countryId];

    //Set up to get the thing you want to update
    NSFetchRequest * request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Country" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]];
    [request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"countryId = %@", country.countryId]];

    NSError *error = nil;
    country = [[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] lastObject];

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error getting the country from core data: %@", error);
    }

    country.downloaded = 1;

    error = nil;
    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Saving changes to country failed: %@", error);
    }
}
```

FetchedResultsController:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    /*
     Set up the fetched results controller.
     */
    // Create the fetch request for the entity.
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Country" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // Sort using the name property.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDownloaded = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"downloaded" ascending:NO];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortName = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[sortDownloaded, sortName]];

    // Use the sectionIdentifier property to group into sections.
    _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"downloaded" cacheName:nil];
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = _fetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Initializing Restkit:

```
//Enable RestKit logging
//RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/ObjectMapping", RKLogLevelInfo);
//RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/CoreData", RKLogLevelTrace);
//RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Network", RKLogLevelTrace);

// Initialize RestKit
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:BaseURLString]];

// Initialize managed object store
NSError *error = nil;
NSURL *modelURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"FGDataModel" ofType:@"momd"]];
NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];

BOOL success = RKEnsureDirectoryExistsAtPath(RKApplicationDataDirectory(), &error);
if (!success) {
    RKLogError(@"Failed to create Application Data Directory at path '%@': %@", RKApplicationDataDirectory(), error);
}

objectManager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore;

NSString *path = [RKApplicationDataDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"FGDataModel.sqlite"];
NSPersistentStore *persistentStore = [managedObjectStore addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:path fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:nil withConfiguration:nil options:nil error:&error];

if (! persistentStore) {
    RKLogError(@"Failed adding persistent store at path '%@': %@", path, error);
}

// Configure a managed object cache to ensure we do not create duplicate objects
managedObjectStore.managedObjectCache = [[RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:managedObjectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext];

[managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];

// Set the default store shared instance
[RKManagedObjectStore setDefaultStore:managedObjectStore];

// Setup our object mappings
[FGDataCalls setupObjectMappings:managedObjectStore withObjectManager:objectManager];

// Save the MOC
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
appDelegate.managedObjectContext = managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext;
```

I've tried saving the context as many different ways at this point, including blocks, and I haven't yet had the fetchedResultsController recognize the update and even call `controllerWillChangeContent:` or `controllerDidChangeContent:`. I have successfully deleted a row using the MOC's `deleteObject:` method, so I have the context in the correct state. I can even get the object from my fetchedResultsController after the downloaded attribute has been set and see that it is correct, but the table never updates. Additionally, forcing the table to reload after I have changed the attribute doesn't yield any result. I know this is a specific case, but hopefully someone else has run into the same issue or can see where I'm going wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: Is 'downloaded' property a `NSNumber` or a scalar type? Did you check “Use scalar properties for primitive data types” when generating NSManagedObject from .xcdatamodel?

Comment: Please show your FRC delegate methods!

Comment: I can add them, but they are all just the Apple boilerplate methods at the moment. They aren't being called anyway when I make changes to the FRC

Comment: Oh wow Michal thank you so much. I had no idea I couldn't use a scalar type, and Core Data gave no indication that it was failing due to me trying to save an NSInteger. Changed to an `NSNumber` and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

When saving you shouldn't do

```
error = nil;
if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Saving changes to country failed: %@", error);
}
```

you should do

```
error = nil;
if (![self.managedObjectContext saveToPersistentStore:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Saving changes to country failed: %@", error);
}
```

That said, assuming the FRC is connected to the same context then it should see changes before they're saved. You also don't show your FRC delegate methods so there could be an issue there.

Comment: I've tried that as well, but same result. MY FRC delegate methods are all just boilerplate Apple methods at this point, but none of them are accessed when I change the object in the FRC.

Comment: Then I can't see anything obviously wrong. Did you auto-generate your managed object subclasses?

Comment: Solved in the comments above. I didn't know Core Data only worked with `NSNumber` - I'll never forget it now.